# basic Haskell: defining sorting function by recursion

Tags: haskell

So I have slight problem with sorting function. I need to define (using recursion) a function *i*, that takes as an argument a list of arguments *a* (this list needs to belong to *Ord*), which outputs ordered list of elements of type *a*.
Example: 
i [3,2,1] = [1,2,3]

I have managed to come with this solution:

```
i :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]

i [] = []
i (x:xs) 

| x <= head (xs) = x: i xs
| otherwise = i xs : x
```

But it doesn't compute, outputting many errors. What is wrong?

Comment: The formatting of this code is incorrect; however, even after fixing that, there's still some issues.  Look at the type of `(:)` and the return type of `i`; you should find your problem then.

Answer (score 4):

Let me give you some hints to get you started. First of all, let's fix the formatting:

```
i :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
i [] = []
i (x:xs) 
    | x <= head (xs) = x: i xs
    | otherwise = i xs : x
```

This throws an error which says:

```
In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘i xs’
In the expression: i xs : x
```

Now, this expression `i xs : x` is problematic. The type of `(:)` is `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`. But in your expression you are passing a list instead of a value. What you meant to use was possibly `++`. Using that fixes the compile error:

```
i :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
i [] = []
i (x:xs)
    | x <= head (xs) = x: i xs
    | otherwise = i xs ++ [x]
```

Now, if you try it in `ghci`, you will get a runtime exception:

```
ghci> i [3,2,1]
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

Can you guess why ? That's because you haven't handled the case where the list is of length `1`. So handling the case will give you this:

```
i :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
i [] = []
i (x:[]) = [x]
i (x:xs)            
    | x <= head (xs) = x: i xs
    | otherwise = i xs ++ [x]
```

Now, you may think that this works:

```
ghci> i [3,2,1]
[1,2,3]
ghci> i [3,1,2]
[1,2,3]
```

But it doesn't actually work, because there is a flaw in your algorithm. Just comparing the first two elements of the list won't give you an sorted array.

```
ghci> i [2,1,3]
[1,3,2]
```

I hope this is enough to get you started.